# Turret firing the wrong way when I tap the left side of the screen

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am rather new at all of this so I apologize if this is a terribly ignorant question.  I am attempting to make a turret that will rotate to face a tap and fire in that direction.  Some code was found in a tutorial for Ray Wenderlich's rotating turrets and I moved the turret to the bottom center of the screen and also relocated the starting point of the projectiles to the same point. This position is more akin to old missle command style games.

Unfortunately now the weapon fires correctly when I tap the right side of the screen but when I tap the left it fires down and to the right off screen, like it is flipping the command somehow.  Can anyone help me straighten this out?  Is there perhaps an alternate way to code this so that I won't have the left firing issue or do I need to input something additional to translate the coordinates so the taps register properly?

```
// Import the interfaces
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"
#import "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
#import "GameOverLayer.h"
#import "Monster.h"
#import "LevelManager.h"

// Needed to obtain the Navigation Controller
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#pragma mark - HelloWorldLayer

// HelloWorldLayer implementation
@implementation HelloWorldLayer

// Helper class method that creates a Scene with the HelloWorldLayer as the only child.
+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

// return the scene
return scene;
}

- (void) addMonster {

    //CCSprite * monster = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"monster.png"];
    Monster * monster = nil;
    if (arc4random() % 2 == 0) {
        monster = [[[WeakAndFastMonster alloc] init] autorelease];
    } else {
        monster = [[[StrongAndSlowMonster alloc] init] autorelease];
    }

    // Determine where to spawn the monster along the Y axis
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    int minY = monster.contentSize.height / 2;
    int maxY = winSize.height - monster.contentSize.height/2;
    int rangeY = maxY - minY;
    int actualY = (arc4random() % rangeY) + minY;

    // Create the monster slightly off-screen along the right edge,
    // and along a random position along the Y axis as calculated above
    monster.position = ccp(winSize.width + monster.contentSize.width/2, actualY);
    [self addChild:monster];

    // Determine speed of the monster
    int minDuration = monster.minMoveDuration; //2.0;
    int maxDuration = monster.maxMoveDuration; //4.0;
    int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
    int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;

    // Create the actions
    CCMoveTo * actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration position:ccp(-monster.contentSize.width/2, actualY)];
    CCCallBlockN * actionMoveDone = [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node) {
        [_monsters removeObject:node];
        [node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];

        CCScene *gameOverScene = [GameOverLayer sceneWithWon:NO];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:gameOverScene];
    }];
    [monster runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];

    monster.tag = 1;
    [_monsters addObject:monster];

}

-(void)gameLogic:(ccTime)dt {
    [self addMonster];
}

- (id) init
{
    if ((self = [super initWithColor:[LevelManager sharedInstance].curLevel.backgroundColor])) {

        CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        _player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"player2.png"];
        _player.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, 20);
        [self addChild:_player];

        [self schedule:@selector(gameLogic:) interval:[LevelManager sharedInstance].curLevel.secsPerSpawn];

        [self setTouchEnabled:YES];

        _monsters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _projectiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [self schedule:@selector(update:)];

        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"background-music-aac.caf"];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if (_nextProjectile != nil) return;

    // Choose one of the touches to work with
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

    // Set up initial location of projectile
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    _nextProjectile = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"projectile2.png"] retain];
    _nextProjectile.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, 20);

    // Determine offset of location to projectile
    CGPoint offset = ccpSub(location, _nextProjectile.position);

    // Bail out if you are shooting down or backwards
    //if (offset.x <= 0) return;

    // Determine where you wish to shoot the projectile to
    int realX = winSize.width + (_nextProjectile.contentSize.width/2);
    float ratio = (float) offset.y / (float) offset.x;
    int realY = (realX * ratio) + _nextProjectile.position.y;
    CGPoint realDest = ccp(realX, realY);

    // Determine the length of how far you're shooting
    int offRealX = realX - _nextProjectile.position.x;
    int offRealY = realY - _nextProjectile.position.y;
    float length = sqrtf((offRealX*offRealX)+(offRealY*offRealY));
    float velocity = 480/1; // 480pixels/1sec
    float realMoveDuration = length/velocity;

    // Determine angle to face
    float angleRadians = atanf((float)offRealY / (float)offRealX);
    float angleDegrees = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angleRadians);
    float cocosAngle = -1 * angleDegrees;
    float rotateDegreesPerSecond = 180 / 0.5; // Would take 0.5 seconds to rotate 180 degrees, or half a circle
    float degreesDiff = _player.rotation - cocosAngle;
    float rotateDuration = fabs(degreesDiff / rotateDegreesPerSecond);
    [_player runAction:
     [CCSequence actions:
      [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:rotateDuration angle:cocosAngle],
      [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
         // OK to add now - rotation is finished!
         [self addChild:_nextProjectile];
         [_projectiles addObject:_nextProjectile];

         // Release
         [_nextProjectile release];
         _nextProjectile = nil;
     }],
      nil]];

    // Move projectile to actual endpoint
    [_nextProjectile runAction:
     [CCSequence actions:
      [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:realMoveDuration position:realDest],
      [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node) {
         [_projectiles removeObject:node];
         [node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
    }],
      nil]];

    _nextProjectile.tag = 2;

    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"pew-pew-lei.caf"];
}

- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {

    NSMutableArray *projectilesToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (CCSprite *projectile in _projectiles) {

        BOOL monsterHit = FALSE;
        NSMutableArray *monstersToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (Monster *monster in _monsters) {

            if (CGRectIntersectsRect(projectile.boundingBox, monster.boundingBox)) {
                monsterHit = TRUE;
                monster.hp --;
                if (monster.hp <= 0) {
                    [monstersToDelete addObject:monster];
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        for (CCSprite *monster in monstersToDelete) {

            [_monsters removeObject:monster];
            [self removeChild:monster cleanup:YES];

            _monstersDestroyed++;
            if (_monstersDestroyed > 30) {
                CCScene *gameOverScene = [GameOverLayer sceneWithWon:YES];
                [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:gameOverScene];
            }
        }

        if (monsterHit) {
            [projectilesToDelete addObject:projectile];
            [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"explosion.caf"];
        }
        [monstersToDelete release];
    }

    for (CCSprite *projectile in projectilesToDelete) {
        [_projectiles removeObject:projectile];
        [self removeChild:projectile cleanup:YES];
    }
    [projectilesToDelete release];
}


// on "dealloc" you need to release all your retained objects
- (void) dealloc
{
    [_monsters release];
    _monsters = nil;
    [_projectiles release];
    _projectiles = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you should replace your `atanf` with `atan2f`, i.e. replace

```
float angleRadians = atanf((float)offRealY / (float)offRealX);
```

with (notice that `atan2f` accepts `Y` and `X` separately!)

```
float angleRadians = atan2f((float)offRealY, (float)offRealX);
```

Have a look at [Wikipedia article about atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2). You will see that from 0-PI/2 `atanf` and `atan2f` will give you the same result. However, as soon as you go from PI/2 towards PI, you will get negative angles using `atanf` while `atan2f` will produce correct angles.

Comment: Tried the fix and the problem is still identical to before.  I am trying to find another way to code this, I can't imagine something as common as a rotating turret could be this difficult....

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at your code again and noticed other problems as well. I have changed the following pieces:

- "bail out" condition when shooting below (note the order change because otherwise you won't be getting shots after a bailout condition is met for the first time!)
- calculation of `realY` and `realX` - you left the code from Ray's tutorial and set the target position to always be on the right side, while in the code below it is always at the top
- removed `atan`/`atan2` functions and used `ccpToAngle(ccp(offRealX, offRealY))` instead

Below is the part of code that has changed. If you need, I can share the whole modified project but it should suffice to replace the beginning of your `ccTouchesEnded` method.

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (_nextProjectile != nil) return;

    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    // Choose one of the touches to work with
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

    CGPoint targetPosition = ccp(winSize.width / 2, 20);

    // Determine offset of location to projectile
    CGPoint offset = ccpSub(location, targetPosition);

    // Bail out if you are shooting down or backwards
    if (offset.y <= 0)
    {
    return;
    }

    // Set up initial location of projectile
    _nextProjectile = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"projectile2.png"] retain];
    _nextProjectile.position = targetPosition;

    // Determine where you wish to shoot the projectile to
    int realY = winSize.height + (_nextProjectile.contentSize.height/2);
    float ratio = (float) offset.x / (float) offset.y;
    int realX = (realY * ratio) + _nextProjectile.position.x;
    CGPoint realDest = ccp(realX, realY);

    // Determine the length of how far you're shooting
    int offRealX = realX - _nextProjectile.position.x;
    int offRealY = realY - _nextProjectile.position.y;
    float length = sqrtf((offRealX*offRealX)+(offRealY*offRealY));
    float velocity = 480/1; // 480pixels/1sec
    float realMoveDuration = length/velocity;

    // Determine angle to face
    float angleRadians = ccpToAngle(ccp(offRealX, offRealY));
```